# remove original element from an array without removing its duplicates in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, duplicates

I have an array with duplicate elements. I would like to remove one element at a time without iterating in a loop. Also, if I remove an element, if any duplicate element exists for that element it should remain in the array. Is there any way to do this in perl?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, please share it.

Comment: I tried @array = grep {!/^$element$/} @array;   But this is removing duplicate elements also

Comment: `grep` _is_ iterating in a loop. It's hiding that behind the scenes.

Comment: You need to give us a) sample inputs, b) expected outputs and (most importantly) c) your code. Without a and b we would only be guessing at what you mean. Without c, well, we'd probably assume that you were lazy and wanted us to do your homework for you. And don't give us this information in comments - edit your question to add further details.

Comment: @user3248103 As a new user to the site, the correct response is: thank you, I will use that feedback to ask better questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One loop to store elements in hash, and one grep to show remaining elements. All this assuming that `undef` is not occurring as value in your array of duplicates.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @r = (1..8, 1..8);

my %ref;
push @{ $ref{$_} }, \$_ for @r;

my $to_remove = 2;
undef ${shift @{ $ref{$to_remove} }};
print Dumper \@r;

undef ${shift @{ $ref{$to_remove} }};
print Dumper \@r;

print Dumper [ grep defined, @r ];
```